# Capture image with camera in android and save with a custom name

Tags: java, android

i have create an android application that will capture picture and save in sdcard folder,now i want to save the image with a custom name.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.getPath());
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, "new-photo-name.jpg");
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
        {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), photo,
                    null, null);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); 
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

        }
    }
```

here is the code which i have used for capturing the image and save them in the sd card folder,please help me to save the image with a specific name for eg:android.jpeg

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430527/how-to-launch-the-camera-and-take-a-picture. Have searched SO?

Comment: DO you want a generic name for the saved pictures?

Comment: i want to save pic name with a specific name eg: android.jpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myname.jpeg");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos); 
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

you would also need to add Permission in Android Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

the snippet will save the content of `photo` inside `/sdcard` with the name `"myname.jpeg"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put fileName as Intent Extras -

```
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, "android.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.com/2012/04/save-captured-image-to-applications.html) article maybe useful, try it.

& [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728269/saving-image-to-sd-with-current-date-and-time-in-name-doesnt-work) as well, the only different that he used the date as a default name.
change it.

It usually works :)