# No such file or directory issue

Tags: android, image, file-upload, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

I want to upload an image to a server using multipart/form-data. The user selects the image using the image picker like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
act.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

After he picked the image I receive it in the onActivityResult with the following code:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
String filePath = null;

Cursor cursor = act.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]));
    cursor.close();
}

return filePath;
```

So I get the path to the file. When I want to upload the image to the server with this piece of code:

```
File file = new File(filePath);
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

It throws this exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/100LGDSC/CAM00015.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

The problem is, some of the photos are found and uploaded (even on sdcard or not) and some of them not... For example this one is being uploaded:

```
/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/100LGDSC/CAM00008.jpg
```

I have these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

So the question is clear, what could be the reason that some of the images could not be found?

Comment: Do you have internet permission?

Comment: Do one thing. Save the photo user chose in a new location. Then pick it from then.Once it uploaded , delete it.

Comment: yes, I forgot that one to add here.

Comment: So the problem is that the MediaStore returns a URI to an image that does not exist? - a) Does the file actually exist? b) Are you sure you're resolving the URI correctly via the content provider (what's `act`)?

Comment: The user just picks an image that really exists on the device. I checked it also outside my app - in the photo gallery and the path is exact the same like that in the filenotfoundexception... With some of them it works good, like I wrote in the post... act is the activity from where I'm calling the image picker.

Comment: Is there any apparent pattern to those files which do work and those that don't? (Like internal vs. external storage or the like.)

Comment: On LG - The photo is on the phone but if I go to the details in the photo gallery, some information are missing - like resolution, manufacturer etc. Those where this information IS present are found in my code. On Samsung - there is no difference in details between those that are not found and that are allright. Very strange bug or what. On my OnePlus - everything is okay.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment. Here is the details of it.
In some devices , when you capture an image they save it to your device at once, but some devices wont do this (it's also depends upon the user settings ). And also if you capture an image using s5 or any other mobile which have high resolution camera , the image size will be between 5 to 10 mb . It's not a batter approach to upload such high size image to server. My advice will be , you must capture an image , save it in your mobile , compress it and upload it. After this you can delete it also. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374701/capture-image-with-camera-in-android-and-save-with-a-custom-name) and link for help , he is saving and compressing an image. And read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) for batter understanding of bitmaps etc.

Comment: OP said "The user selects the image using the image picker" -- No need for his app to capture or store anything anywhere.

Comment: Well then you must compress this, That's the approach I used mostly to effectively upload images etc.

Comment: What is really happening  is your case as far as I understand , once you capture an image , and request to upload , the image is not in your device. Which is probably  not saved in you device.

Comment: I worked on an app , and face this issue . The code was working perfectly on samsang devices while having this issue (the one you are facing ) in htc devices. That's why I advised. Rest is upon you , Happy Coding.

Comment: Where did you get the image file's location from in your app?

Comment: Once you capture it , in your on activity result you have this file path etc , But once you passed this code , the file is might be deleted , you have file path in your variable , but the specific image at that location is no more .

Comment: see this http://www.codepool.biz/take-a-photo-from-android-camera-and-upload-it-to-a-remote-php-server.html
he is storing it in a bitmap , now that captured image is in a bitmap . You must do something like this. Understand your problem, once you understood it , you will find tons of solution , I proposed just two of them.